# How to determine the Supremum and Infimum in a Hasse Doagram?

Tags: lattice-orders

In order to find the supremum or infimum of a Hasse diagram we follow the outgoing lines from the elements *up* for supremum or *down* for infimum until the lines meet each other.

My question is, do we have to go only straight or are we allowed to turn left or right until we reach the meeting point. In this diagram for example I know the **Sup ({c,d}) = 1** but what about the **Inf**? Is the **Inf ( {c,d} ) = 0** or doesn't it exists?

[image]

Is there any difference in the meaning if two elements are directly connected or not? What is for example the difference between **Sup ({b,e}) = e** and **Sup ({b,c}) = e** or **Sup({d,1}) = 1** and **Sup({d,c}) = 1**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as that. In my opinion, it is better to use (or at least think of) the terms *least upper bound* instead of *supremum* and *greatest lower bound* instead of *infimum*.

So for example, $1$ is an upper bound of $b$ and $c$ (go from $b$ to $d$ to $1$ and from $c$ to $e$ to $1$), but it is not the *least* upper bound, because $e$ is also an upper bound of $b$ and $c$, and it is lower than $1$.
So yes, you are allowed to go left or right, but you can not just pick an arbitrary upper bound, you have to find the least one.

$\inf\{c,d\} = 0$, because $0$ is the *only* lower bound of $c$ and $d$. When you say "directly connected", it simply means that one of the elements is a lower bound of both of them, and the other element is an upper bound of both of them. For example, when taking the supremum of $b$ and $e$, notice that $e$ is an upper bound of $b$, and it is also an upper bound of itself. Clearly, for any element $x$ there can be no element which is both an upper bound of $x$ *and* less than $x$, so $e$ is also the *least* upper bound. So for "directly connected" elements, one of the two must be the supremum and one of the two must be the infimum. This is also how one can recover the ordering using supremums and infimums: $a \leq b$ iff $\inf\{a,b\} = a$ iff $\sup\{a,b\} = b$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be nice if you could also explain the second part of the question - the meaning if two elements are directly connected or not but have the same Sup. or Inf.

Comment: @Infinity that is what my last part of the answer is about.